# Testrpc transactions are failing. How do I perform a transaction when Mist cannot estimate gas?

Tags: testrpc, gas-estimate, ethereumjs

I am attempting to perform transactions and create contracts using EthereumJS Testrpc. I set it up by running the following:

Terminal 1: `testrpc`

Terminal 2: `mist --rpc localhost:8545`

Running both of these seem to work, and Mist opens. Everything appears like it is working, but when I go to send a transaction, I get the following:

[image]

Mist connects to no peers when I open it this way. Does this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer : https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/236#issuecomment-338070203
(github user **benjamincburns** probably will fix this soon)